# Groovy - SoapUI - How to download file to a specific path

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new and learning Groovy scripting, I have task to write a code to download file to a given path.

code I am trying:

```
def myTestFile = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/test.pdf")
def outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(myTestFile)
outStream.close()
```

Issue I am facing:
File is not being saved to specified path

Comment: add what u have tried ..!

Comment: Please have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Code I was trying is correct code, due to write access issue file not being saved in specified folder.

Below code is saving file into specified path

```
def myTestFile = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/suman.pdf")
def outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(myTestFile)
outStream.close()
```